# Django creacion del proyecto

Tags: python, django

Estoy practicando Django, a la hora de crear un proyecto no entiendo porque cuando pongo **django-admin startproject config** (nombre de la carpeta) ya creado el **pipenv** me crea 2 carpetas llamadas **config** (adjunto foto)
[image: Creacion del proyecto Django]

Entonces tengo que mover la carpeta de config, carpeta creada de manera default, para tenerlo bien porque o si no cuando lo ejecuto **python manage.py runserver** no reconoce la el archivo porque me lo metio en una sub-carpeta.

Por ente, tengo que moverlo para poder ejecutar el comando, donde quedaria asi (adjunto foto)

[image: Carpeta config creada correctamente]

Hay manera de que no cree subcarpetas o tengo que precisamente moverlo,

Espero la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que ejecutar el comando de esta manera:

```
django-admin startproject config /mnt/c/Users/Saint/Desktop/helloworld
```

De esta manera Django usara el directorio existente como directorio de proyecto, esto significa que creara el manage.py y la app config dentro del directorio helloworld

Puedes leer un poco mas de esto aqui:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#startproject